# Select for update along with "select count clause" from other thread

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, locking

As per our requirement, we lock a table with `select for update` lock while fetching the data. This way, no other thread picks up that data.

I just wanted to confirm if `select count(*) from table where column1=value1` will retrieve locked rows.

If yes, will it retrieve recent changes made at the end of `select for update` locking (i.e. will it wait for rows to be updated) or stale data will be shown?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . It depends on the TX isolation level.

2 . Lock means `stop and wait` but not `skip`.